# Query value from XML data element

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query which returns data from a column. However the data in the column is in XML. I need value inside value element. How can I do so?

Please see my below SQL query.

```
SELECT 
    A.[business_line]
FROM
    [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A
INNER JOIN
    [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_REG_MST_LOOKUP] B ON B.code = A.product_substance_type
```

The output to this query is

```
<collection><object parentid="ce57cc75-3966-478f-bf25-5e3abf716f96" parenttype="Object"><fields><field name="code"><value>BL2</value></field></fields></object></collection>
```

I want the value `BL2` from this. The data is inside the `value` element. Can anyone help how to do so? I tried using stuff but I wasn't able to get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`XML.value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) does the trick as follows:

```
declare @Test xml = '<collection><object parentid="ce57cc75-3966-478f-bf25-5e3abf716f96" parenttype="Object"><fields><field name="code"><value>BL2</value></field></fields></object></collection>';

select @Test.value('(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]', 'varchar(3)' )
```

Returns:

```
BL2
```

So add that to your query:

```
select A.[business_line].value('(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]', 'varchar(3)'
from [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A
inner join [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_REG_MST_LOOKUP] B
    on B.code = A.product_substance_type
```

As you have indicated that `A.[business_line]` is not of `XML` datatype, just convert it before calling `value`:

```
convert(xml, A.[business_line]).value
```

Note: I have assumed that its only ever a 3 character result i.e. `varchar(3)` but if not adjust to suit.

Comment: Its giving error.Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max). Do I need to cast or convert it into xml? @dale

Comment: Well yes, ideally you would store XML in an XML datatype, but if its not then just cast/convert it.

Comment: Can you assist?

Comment: I run this query.   select convert(xml, A.[business_line]).value('(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]', 'varchar(3)')
from [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A
inner join [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_REG_MST_LOOKUP] B
    on B.code = A.product_substance_type

Comment: I am getting a new error now. Msg 9413, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 30, A string literal was expected

Comment: Invalid XML... sorry can't help then. You'll need some form of raw string parsing solution.

Comment: If its not too late, start storing you XML as valid XML in an XML datatype column. That will save you a lot of issues later.

Comment: Oh.. I will post this as a seperate xml related issue. Lets see if someone helps me on xml

Comment: That XML is valid, but you have some invalid XML in your database which is causing that error.

Comment: Oh.... Will see how to handle it... Thanks for your help mate..